# SQL Server: how to do an efficient cross join

Tags: sql-server

My data is structured as follows:

```
create table data (id int, cluster int, weight float);
insert into data values (99,1,4);
insert into data values (99,2,3);
insert into data values (99,3,4);
insert into data values (1234,2,5);
insert into data values (1234,3,2);    
insert into data values (1234,4,3);
```

Then I have to impute some values because the vector is of certain lenght x:

```
declare @startnum int=0
declare @endnum int=4036;
with gen as (select @startnum as num
             union ALL
             select num+1 from gen where num+1<=@endnum)
select * into gen from gen -- store the numbers
option(maxrecursion 10000)
```

I then have to cross join the values stored in gen but this is done on two very large tables (not as in the current example), currently my query is running for over 2 hours and I start to think there is something wrong. Any ideas on how I can make this procedure faster and more correct?

Here's what I doing right now.

```
select id, cluster, max(v) as weight
from (select id, cluster, case when cluster=num then weight else 0 end as v
     from data
          cross join gen) cross_num
group by id, cluster;
go
```

EDIT: It is the last query that is running very slowly, and of course I have a super large dataset :)

Note: I also wonder what the Paste the Plan is exactly, I actually don't know how to look for this, can someone give me a resource I can look up and try to understand it?

Comment: Posting the query plan would be a start, via Paste the Plan. Explaining what you are trying to achieve would be another. Using a `DISTINCT` with a `GROUP BY` in the same scope, however, is always a sign of a problem. The `GROUP BY` should already be putting your data into distinct groups, so either the `GROUP BY` is wrong or the `DISTINCT` is pointless (and just adds unnecessary expense to your query).

Comment: `case when cluster=cluster then weight else 0 end`? Apart from when it has the value `NULL` when does `cluster` *not* equal itself? `CASE WHEN cluster IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE weight END` would be much more sensible syntax. I also really suggest you qualify your columns in that subquery with the table name (or better yet, alias the table, and use those for the qualifier).

Comment: Sorry can you explain, for what you are using your gen table? Just to output multiple identical rows? No value from gen seems to be used anyway.

Comment: Sorry for this, the value from gen is num and is used in case when cluster=num. I need this step to make the vectors the same length as I will compare them later on. And yes it's to output identical rows for each id

Comment: Well, recursion is a slow way to make a numbers rowset but I doubt that's the issue here since it's only 400 rows.

Comment: So I just tried your code and took about 1 second on my SQL Server.  What else aren't you telling us?

Comment: RBarryYoung the issue is with the last query with the cross join, not the recursive. The query which is lasting forever is the cross join, I added the two first steps for completeness. Obviously the real data is much much larger about 8Million rows, is there a workaround or do I have no other choice then to wait?

Comment: So now we really need the query plan.  Here's instructions on how to get it and paste it here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/382341/how-to-include-an-sql-server-execution-plan-to-a-stack-overflow-question

Comment: If you convert the rCTE to an inline tally, that would give some performance benefit. If the `CROSS JOIN` to `gen` is *actually* a `CROSS JOIN` to the CTE `gen`, and not the table `gen`, it will likely be a significant performance benefit.

Comment: Sorry Larnu, I am not sure I understand. Do you mean to put the CTE for generating the numbers (step 2) as a subquery in the `cross join`? i.e., instead of joining with gen table?

Comment: No, the gen table is better than an inline tally. People are just confused that you used a recursive CTE to create a tally table, and that that query has nothing at all to do with the query that's running for 2 hours.

Comment: I don't understand why this isn't a simple join and group `select id, cluster, max(weight) as weight from gen g left join data d on d.cluster = g.num group by d.id, d.cluster;`

Comment: @Charlieface because I need to generate a paired combination for a list of numbers ranging from 0-4036 and not just for 1,2,3,4 . I need all my ids (in my real data) to have 4036 rows, some of these rows have actual values and some don't, its actual quite sparse. That's why I need a `cross join`

Comment: And that is why you take `gen g left join data d` rather than `data d join gen g`, that way you get all the rows from `gen`, even the ones with no matching row in `data`. I don't get your current query, you will get loads of rows with all values `null`

Comment: @Mars if you are saying that you are crossing 8 million rows with 4000+ rows than the problem is that you are forcing it to hash and sort 32 billion rows.  It is very difficult for us to advise you on this because your query doesn't seem to make sense. Specifically the `GROUP BY` seems to just be cancelling out your `CROSS JOIN`.

Comment: @Charlieface I think that you should just post that as an answer.

Comment: @Charlieface this is exactly why I need that cross join to have many rows without any values, in this case 0s (given the `case` command) for each id. Using your suggestion I loose all the ids, everything becomes NULLs. @RBarryYoung the `GROUP BY` does not cancel the cross join, it is used because of `Max(v)`. CROSS JOINS create duplicates hence the aggregated function in the outer query is used to deduplicate the results. Thank you all for the answers, the query runs after 2 hours , sometimes you just need the data and there is no optimization possible. Cheers everyone.

Answer (score 1):

So, the problem here is that you're creating a massive Cartesian product and aggregating at the same time.

However, we might be able to cheat if your data lines up well. This may also totally backfire if it lines up poorly. I can't see your data so I don't know what's going on.

I'm going to write this using an empty staging table or temp table. You could write it as a series of CTE expressions, but in my experience those do not perform quite as well. Ideally you can take these queries and wrap them in a stored procedure.

So, the primary key for your table can't be `id, cluster`, because you're aggregating on that group. If `id, cluster` is not very selective -- meaning that there are a lot of records for each `id, cluster` combination -- then we might be able to significantly reduce the amount of work done here. If there's 5 records for each `id, cluster`, then this will probably not help much but if there's 100,000 for each `id, cluster` then it will probably help a lot.

First, create your `gen` table. I recommend creating a clustered primary key on `gen.num`.

Second, let's start building the data. Remember, I'm assuming `StagingTable` is empty.

Here's the first query that does the real work:

```
INSERT INTO StagingTable (id, cluster, weight)
SELECT id, cluster, MAX(weight) AS weight
FROM data
GROUP BY id, cluster
```

The query would benefit from an index, but it will depend on your data if `id, cluster, weight` is better or worse than `cluster, id, weight`. However, before you run this you should disable any indexes on `StagingTable` and then rebuild the index after running at least this first insert.

Depending on your data, you may require or benefit from or should avoid using a `WHERE cluster BETWEEN 0 AND 4036` clause on the above query as well. It's not clear to me if there are 4037 clusters numbered 0 to 4036, or if you're only interested in clusters 0 to 4036 but there are more, or if you're only interested in creating "default" records of weight `0` for clusters 0 to 4036 but want all clusters aggregated if they happen to go higher.

Now, think about what's in `StagingTable`. Everything that we've loaded into that table is everywhere that there is an `id, cluster` in the `data` table. Critically, every `id` we might need will be in `StagingTable`, even if it's missing one or more values for `cluster`.

Now we just need to fill in the missing `cluster` values for each `id`, and we know that the `weight` of the missing clusters is `0`.

```
INSERT INTO StagingTable (id, cluster, weight)
SELECT DISTINCT s.id, g.num, 0
FROM StagingTable s
INNER JOIN gen g
    ON g.num BETWEEN 0 AND 4036
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM StagingTable s2
        WHERE s2.id = s.id
            AND s2.cluster = g.num
    )
```

The `INNER JOIN gen g ON g.num BETWEEN 0 AND 4036` may not be necessary if `gen` is always going to be numbers 0 to 4036. In that case you can just use `CROSS JOIN gen g`.

The EXISTS is necessary to remove the duplicate rows.

Again, this query could benefit from an index on `StagingTable`, but without seeing your actual data it's a little difficult to tell exactly what you need `(id, cluster)` is one possibility, but `(cluster, id)` may actually work better. Ideally, it should be a clustered primary key.

Edit: Just realized my original second query wouldn't work in some cases. I've modified it to correct the logic.